# Change one value uploaded from a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form.

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="e1" id="e1" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="e2" id="e2" value="2" />
  <input type="text" name="e3" id="e3" value="3" />
  <input type="text" name="e4" id="e4" value="4" />
  <input type="text" name="e5" id="e5" value="5" />
</form>
```

I use the jQuery validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate and submit the form.

```
var validator=$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {},
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data1=$(form).find(':input');
        var data2=data1.serializeArray();
        //Use ajax to post data2 or submit form...
    }
});
```

Instead of submitting the exact values in the form, I would like to change one of them.  For instead, the server should receive a value of "333" instead of "3" for `$_POST['e3']`.

I don't wish to change the value of the `#e3` input on the page.  I would rather not use a hidden input to do so, nor manually create my object to upload.  How do I change either the `data1` object or `data2` object to reflect the new value for `#e3`?

EDIT.  Live example at http://jsfiddle.net/rueL9y0p/1/  data1 and data2 values are:

```
Object { 0=input#e1, 1=input#e2, 2=input#e3, more...}

[Object { name="e1", value="1"}, Object { name="e2", value="2"}, Object { name="e3", value="3"}, Object { name="e4", value="4"}, Object { name="e5", value="5"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the value of the element just before it's submitted, and the serialized array will reflect the new value.  Then after your ajax (or after you serialize the data for your ajax), you can easily change the value back to the original.

Insert your conditional logic as needed...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var original = $('#e3').val();   // original value
    $('#e3').val('your new value');  // insert new value
    // ajax() here                   // submit via ajax
    $('#e3').val(original);          // change the value back after the ajax is complete
}
```

Maybe you'll want to change the value back from within the `ajax()` `complete` callback function.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rueL9y0p/4/**

Comment: Note my requirement "I don't wish to change the value of the `#e3` input on the page."  The reason is I use Ajax and don't always redirect the page, thus I don't want the user to see these changes.

Comment: @user1032531, you did not show your ajax, but changing the value back after ajax is complete is just as trivial as changing it immediately before the ajax.  I honestly don't see any problem with that.  However, I cannot understand why you're not simply changing the value with the server side logic... that's really the best place for this.

Comment: Good point about changing it back afterwards!  I feel like a dummy.  Do you mind if I edit your answer to state so, or would you like to?  In regards to changing the value server-side, I have reasons not to wish to do so (let me know if you wish to know them).

Comment: @user1032531, I've edited my answer accordingly.  I don't need to know why you cannot do this on the server side.  However, I'm very curious why you're changing a value on a form.  Why not just validate the form so that the value is entered correctly in the first place?  In other words, what's the point of having a form to collect data if you're going to over-ride it?

Comment: Thanks.  Instead of moving it back after the ajax, it could be moved back immediately after the form is serialized.

Comment: In hindsight, I should change my approach. I have an input where the user types some text, and a jQueryUI autocomplete plugin returns the matched text, and when clicked, puts the text in the input and also puts the ID associated with the returned text in a data variable. I then am moving the ID stored into the data variable into the original input before submitting to the server. I should remove the name from the input which displays the text, and just use a hidden input with a name to store the returned id. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, although you specifically said you didn't want to use a hidden variable, I think that's the best approach.  This is typically how situations are handled when the data element and the GUI element are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just as another solution, you could [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the form and make changes to the cloned element.

e.g.

```
var formClone = form.clone(),
    name = formClone.find('#name');

name.val('NEW VALUE');
```

You would then serialize the cloned form and send that data off to the server.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcn6dw8z/)

Comment: haim770 previously had an answer, but he must have deleted it.  Something like `data.forEach(function(i) { if (i.name === 'e3') i.value = '333' })`.  Seemed like he was on to something, just needed to correct the jQuery, no?

Comment: My bad, even his JavaScript was fine.

Comment: Do you think his or your answer is best?

Answer (score 0):

haim770 previously posted this as an answer, but he later deleting it.  Seems good to me.  Any reason why he might have deleted it?

```
var data1 = $('#myForm').find(':input');
var data2 = data1.serializeArray();
console.log(data1);
console.log(data2);
data2.forEach(function(i) { if (i.name === 'e3') i.value = '333' });
console.log(data2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rueL9y0p/3/